# Method won't fire when called

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I have this custom created object called MyAlertView, I'm creating an instance of it like this:

`MyAlertView *alertView2 = [[MyAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"TITLE" message:@"MESSAGE"      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"CANCEL" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];`

the initializer works just fine and initializes the object.
then I call this method:

```
[alertView2 show];
```

this is the method implementation in MyAlertView Class:

```
- (void)show {
    [self.delegate willPresentAlertView:self];
    [self.myWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.delegate didPresentAlertView:self];
}
```

I set a breakpoint there but the method just don't get called.
why is that?

Comment: are  you sure....`the initializer works just fine and initializes the object.`

Comment: if the method is not fired it means that receiver is nil.

Comment: Indeed @AnoopVaidya I set it to nil later and forget about that so when i call `show` it is nil. thanks.

Comment: Do you really want to override alertview show method

Comment: @thatzprem I'm not subclassing AlertView its a custom class so the show method you see is something i wrote.